# Why this regular expression returns true, while by any means of logics should return false?

Tags: javascript, regex

The code:
`/^(Mr)|(Hr)\./.test("Mr#DOSHI")`
returns "true". Why? I have told the program: "String must begin with either "Mr" or "Hr" and then be followed by a dot". In this string "Mr" is not followed by dot, but it still returns "true". Why?

Comment: The `|` operator applies to everything on the left. So what you want is `/^(Mr)\.|^(Hr)\./`

Comment: slebetman, thank you! Now I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String must begin with either "Mr" or "Hr" and then be followed by a dot". In this string "Mr" is not followed by dot

That isn't what your code says. It really means:

Either:

- The string must begin with Mr *or*
- The string my contain Hr followed by a full stop

The regex you are looking for it:

```
/^(Mr|Hr)\./
```

Although you probably aren't looking to *capture* that match, so:

```
/^(?:Mr|Hr)\./
```

… might be closer.

Comment: `/^[MH]r\./` would work as well if capturing isn't required.

Comment: "The string must begin with Mr or
The string my contain Hr followed by a full stop" - why is it this way? Why the dot was connected to the "or" operator despite the fact, what no parenthesis were uniting them?

Comment: @JaroslavTavgen — Because the `|` is stronger